# Need help in understanding this enumerate function

Tags: python-3.x, enumerate

I can not understand this python code, especially the if block of the code, I understand that we are adding the 'th' word at the end of the numbers but didn't understand why 11, 12 and 13 are added separately in this. any help would be appreciated

```
def attach_ordinal(num):
    """Convert an interger to an ordinal string, eg. 2 -> '2nd'."""
    suffixces = {str(i): v for i, v in enumerate(['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th',
                                                  'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th'])}
    v = str(num)
    # special case in early teens
    if v in {'11', '12', '13'}:
        return v + 'th'
    return v + suffixes[v[-1]]
```

Comment: Try running the code without the special case and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is already mentioned in the commented code:

11, 12 and 13 are special ordinals because they do not follow the **1st, 2nd or 3rd** ordinal rule, instead are **11th, 12th, 13th**.

```
def attach_ordinal(num):
"""Convert an interger to an ordinal string, eg. 2 -> '2nd'."""
```

Order for ordinal suffix goes from 0 - 9 according to the code below,  although this only applies for every ten number set other than the teens set because there **no such thing as 11st or 12nd or 13rd**

```
suffixces = {str(i): v for i, v in enumerate(['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th',
                                              'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th'])}
v = str(num)
```

That's why the special case for the early teens:

```
# special case in early teens
if v in {'11', '12', '13'}:
    return v + 'th'
return v + suffixes[v[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because every number whose unit place has 1 is spelled as (1 - first ,21 - twenty-first, 31 - thirty-first, etc) but not 11, its spelled Eleventh. Same is the case with 12(twelfth) and 13(thirteenth)